# Linux equivalent of "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" on Windows?

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates

Where I live we have a corporate firewall which is configured to need a certificate installed on the computers in the house for it to be able to scan for vulnerabilities in secure connections. Without it, a few things won't work as the firewall behaves as a man in the middle, and of course a few websites will deny access to prevent any harm as it looks dangerous.

On Windows, I'd just need to double click the certificate (.p12 extension), insert the password and specify it to be put in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" and be done with it. On Linux, I haven't had much luck in doing that.

I'm running Arch.

Comment: What distribution? The procedure will vary, but usually it involves putting the CA cert in `/etc/ssl/certs` and running `c_rehash`.

Comment: I use Arch. Is there anything I need to do with the file? In `/etc/ssl/certs` there's a bunch of certificates ending with .pem, while mine ends with .p12. @Patrick

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible on Linux: http://serverfault.com/questions/18964/add-a-custom-certificate-authority-to-ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

I don't personally use Arch Linux, but this procedure works on most distributions.

First, you need to extract the CA certificate from your bundle. p12 files are basically a bundle of several components of a certificate.

```
openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -cacerts -in bundle.p12
```

You'll get one or more certificates dumped to your console. If you get more than one, find the one where the `subject` is the same as the `issuer`. This is your root certificate.

Take your root certificate (everything between, and including, the `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `END CERTIFICATE` lines), and save it in a file in `/etc/ssl/certs` with the extension `.pem`.

Then do the following:

```
cd /etc/ssl/certs
c_rehash
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't dump anything in the console or made any files I could peak in.

`[vlad@LV-268 cert]$ openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -cacerts -in cert_Hjemmecert.p12
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
[vlad@LV-268 cert]$ ls
cert_Hjemmecert.p12`

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try `openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -in bundle.p12`. It'll likely output a cert, but whether that cert is the CA cert is whats in doubt.